# Decode PDF417 type barcode images using HTML & JavaScript in desktop as well as mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, pdf417

I would like to decode PDF417 type barcode image using javascript,

https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/js-zxing-pdf417 - This works well in desktop browsers but facing Zxing plugin issues in mobile browsers

I want the functionality in mobile browsers as well. Is there any other alternative solution for this scenario (NodeJS/AngularJS)?

Can anyone help me on the same?

Comment: try this https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @George Thanks! I have edited the question to explain my issue clearly. can you help me on the same?

Answer (score -2):

How about solutions like:

- https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode
- https://cirocosta.github.io/qcode-decoder/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode-reader
- https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/

or even tutorial on the desired encoding

- http://www.codepool.biz/how-to-build-a-web-app-to-read-pdf417-barcode-with-dwt.html

Or maybe I missed the specifics about your question.